# Mysql: ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ALL VALUES?

Tags: mysql

Is there any easy way to update all values after a duplicate key? For example:

```
INSERT INTO published_books
           SELECT * FROM books
           WHERE book_id = book_id
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ?everything?
```

The table has around 50 columns and updating each would be painful. Any ideas?

Comment: for the coder... and for the eyes of the other coders :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `REPLACE INTO` for this purpose:

```
REPLACE INTO published_books SELECT * from books;
```

Comment: Please be aware when using `REPLACE INTO` that it actually deletes and recreates a row with only the information in the insert. It does not update the row as `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` does. For more info see here: http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/replace-into-think-twice

Answer (score 0):

If you can generate the query, you could use something like this (PHP):

```
$fields = array(
    'field_1',
    'field_2',
    'field_3'
);
$query = '
    INSERT INTO table (
    ' . implode(', ', $fields) . '
    ) SELECT
        -- ...
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ';
foreach ($fields as $i => $field) {
    $query .= ($i > 0 ? ', ' : '') . $field . '=VALUES(' . $field . ')';
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
INSERT INTO published_books(col1, col2) 
VALUES (’xxx’, ‘yyy’) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = VALUES(col1)
```

Comment: how would you do the same thing with 50 cols? col1, col2... col50?